# how to save dynamically generated javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on an html form editor. Generated html and javascript code should be saved for later use by another application.
Also, I need to generate javascript functions that allow using generated components from other applications, such as functions for setting and getting generated components data.

problem is:

when dynamically creating javascript code, this code will be evaluated and loaded locally, and I didn't find any way to save that code for later usage by different applications.

for example this code

```
<html>
<body>
<script language="javascript">
 document.write ("<script> alert(1)<\/script>");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

will dynamically add a script that shows "1" as an alert. But changes can't be saved.

the intended result is as follow:

```
<html>
<body>
<script language="javascript">
 alert(1);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Where** do you want to save it?

Comment: use jQuery then try to get the code of your page using $("html").html()

Comment: thanks aimadnet 
I think this will be useful.